# Изменение масштаба окна IE

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, zoom

Я запускаю IE (в общем любой браузер) из программы c# и мне необходимо изменить масштаб отображения страницы сайта. С запуском и открытием страницы проблем нет, но как поменять масштаб? Запускаю так

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("IExplore.exe");
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
startInfo.Arguments = УРЛ
var proc = Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Я так понимаю, что есть какой-то аргумент у startInfo, ничего похожего на zoom я не вижу

Подскажите пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

Согласно [документации на Internet Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/general-info/hh826025(v=vs.85)), у него нет аргумента командной строки для изменения масштаба страницы. Соответственно, никакими аргументами `startInfo` вашу задачу не решить.

Решением вашей задачи могла бы быть имитация нажатия кнопки увеличения масштаба на панели инструментов IE, имитация нажатия комбинации горячих клавиш (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>) или жестов мыши (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+колесо мыши) после запуска приложения.